# angular post trigger catch even though statuscode 201

Tags: angularjs

i've created a service to handle signUp with two callbacks. However even though the statusCode is 201 and succesfull it still seem to log `error` in console from the `console.log('error')`. I'm wondering how that can happen when i look on my code i'm calling `errorCallback` in `catch`??

**service**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('KryptoApp')
    .factory('Authentication', Authentication);

    Authentication.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http'];

    function Authentication($cookies, $http) {

    var Authentication = {
        register: register
    };

    return Authentication;
    function register(email, password, username, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        return $http.post('/api/v1/accounts/', {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email
        })
        .then(successCallback)
        .catch(errorCallback)
    }
    function login(email, password) {
        return $http.post('/api/v1/auth/login/', {
        email: email, password: password
        });
    }
    }
})();
```

**controller**

```
   Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.username, function(result){
      // Success callback
      $timeout(function(){
        vm.success = true;
        vm.loading = false;
      }, 2000);
      console.log('success');
    }, function(result){
      // Error callback
      console.log('error');
      var response = result.data
      vm.error = true;
      if (response.email != undefined) {
        vm.error_msg = response.email[0];
      } else {
        vm.error_msg = 'Uventet fejl. prøv igen senere!'
      }

      vm.loading = false;
    });
```

Comment: Oh the promise antipattern. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: i'm not sure how that is related to my case. this does not explain why it execute catch on a 201 status code request?

Comment: Indeed. I posted it as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: i get this on console on call ` "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"`

Comment: @PeterPik can you tell me what happens if you print out `result` in the error callback? I suspect what is happening is that there is an exception being thrown rather than the 201 causing the error callback to be called